# can a simple diode and resistor in series qualify as an inverter?

Tags: digital-logic, resistors, diodes, inverter, logic-gates

I'm working on a single-sided PCB and I find transistor pins are too close together for tracks to run through, so I'm wondering if I could roll off my own inverter by using the cathode of a diode as input and anode connected to a pull-up resistor as output.

Would I be able to apply this circuit to logic gates without problems if my resistor is 10k and the diode is the 1N4007 kind?

I want to avoid using an inverter IC just for one inverter.

**EDIT: this is the proposed solution**

[image: schematic]

Comment: Schematic maybe?

Comment: A schematic would help, but I don't think the circuit you're describing will be an inverter. The output will be low when the input is low and high when the input is high. It could be useful as a non-inverting level shifter.

Comment: you might want to consider saying NOT gate instead of inverter , since it makes confusion with dc to ac inverter

Comment: yes it will work , i will edit your question and add the schematic

Comment: it won't work, check out the schematics Photon included.  Also by nature diode-only logic is non-inverting ... makes sense but I finally realized that rule of thumb today.

Comment: Transistors come in different packages.  Some of them have enough space to route tracks through. http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/on-semiconductor/MMBT2222ALT1G/MMBT2222ALT1GOSCT-ND/1139806

Answer (score 3):

No, your circuit does not invert.  When IN is driven low, it should be fairly obvious that OUT will then be driven low thru the diode.  OUT will be one diode drop above IN, or Vcc, whichever is lower.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm working on a single-sided PCB and I find transistor pins are too close together for tracks to run through, ...

Just spread the legs of the transistor.

[image]

*Figure 1. Spreading the legs of a transistor is quite acceptable if machine insertion is not being used.*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out my mistake, Photon.  This does not create an inverting function.

Diode logic, without any transistors, by nature creates non-inverting functions (and, or, buffer).

For a more solid, proper inverter, I would recommend CMOS instead, requiring one PMOS and one NMOS only.  This would still require 2 components (6 vs. 4 connections, though) and would give full rail logical signals, with lower output resistance.

Comment: Also, it won't be an inverter. Output will be low when input is low. Output will be high when input is high.

Answer (score 0):

This is the circuit I think you're describing:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fENteo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit does not invert. The output is low(ish) when the input is low, and high when the input is high.

This circuit might be useful as a non-inverting level translator between a high voltage logic family and a lower-voltage logic family.

Comment: Thats exactly the circuit im describing